# How to add a permission check to many links before firing their click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many different types of links, which have click event handlers. For example:

```
$('a.category-one').click(function() {});

$('a.category-two').click(function() {});
```

Now I want to add a permission check. When one clicks on a link, this check should decide whether to proceed with the other defined event handler. If the other event handler should not be invoked, then display a modal window to explain why the action on a link is stopped. If it should proceed, then just let it go ahead silently.

I have been struggling about what is the best way to do this with Javascript. I think  about modifying each handler by adding the permission check, but feel it may be too intrusive and such a check is kind of cross-cutting. I think about adding a class to each of the links and attaching the permission check to such a class, but feel the sequence of events might not be  what I expect, and not sure how to stop invoking the second handler from within the first handler.

I want to hear how experts out there say about this.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: _“but feel the sequence of events might not be what I expect”_ – event handlers are executed in the order in which they are attached …

Comment: <a class="a b">link</a>. you mean the handler for class a is always fired before that for class b? Can class a's handler stop innovking that of class b? Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: No, that’s not what I mean. This has nothing to do with how you _select_ the elements, but with the order in which you bind/attach multiple event handlers of the same type to them.

Answer (score 1):

I was also thinking you could add class permissions to the links, but if you add a more complex permission check this could get ugly.  Still, it's a possibility and makes your javascript methods a little more readable.

What if rather than inline methods on the click events you rather call a wrapper method?  It could also end up DRYing up some of the overlap functionality of the click events if there are any.

EDIT:

So for your click events you could do

```
$('a.category-one').click(eventAction($(this));
$('a.category-two').click(eventAction($(this));

function eventAction(control) {

  // Permission check here

  if control.hasClass('category-one') {
   ...
  }
  if control.hasClass('category-two') {
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Mark, is it possible to add some skeleton script to show your idea? Thanks!

Comment: Added some pseudo script, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the simplest way to do this is adding a class like `.permission-check` to the links you want to check, and then use an `onclick` function like this, which prevents the default behavior if some condition happens:

```
$('a.permission-check').click(function(e) {
    if ( /* no permission */ ) e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

On the other hand, if your elements have more handlers and you want to stop all the other handlers if the permission check fails you will need to create a permission check funcion and then use it inside every handler, like this:

```
function permissionCheck(element) {
    // do something with the element
    // then return true if it is ok, false if not
    if ( /* some condition */ ) return true; // permission
    return false; // no permission
}

$('a.category-x').click(function(e) {
    if (!permissionCheck(this)) e.preventDefault();
    // something else...
});
```

Comment: Marco, you mean I should have something like <a class="permission-check category-one">link</a>? Is the permission check handler for .permission-check guaranteed to fire before that for category-one in all browsers? Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: Yes, it is obviously guaranteed! Every browser can handle click events!

Comment: Marco, I mean every browser always invokes .permission-check handler BEFORE invoking that for .category-one for <a class="permission-check category-one">link</a>?

Comment: It doesn't matter which the other classes are. You can do class="class1 class2 hello permission-check class3 ok" and it will still work. The only thing that you need to perform the check is that the element has got the class permission-check.

Comment: Marco, what I want to achieve is that if permission-check fails, ALL OTHER handlers attached to other classes should not get invoked. So I need to guarantee that .permission-check handler gets invoked first.